# Java range input confusion

Tags: java, recursion, user-input, increment, towers-of-hanoi

I have worked out a towers of hanoi program today, and the last step for me is to implement in my code a range for the inputs.

The program will ask for the minimum number of discs, and the maximum number of discs. With this range, the program should solve the puzzle for each incremented number of discs within this range.

Example (according to my code):

Enter the minimum number of Discs: 3
Enter the maximum number of Discs: 6

The output would solve for 3,4,5 and 6 discs, respectively.

**RANGE IS WORKING NOW EXCEPT, if I have an input of say
Enter the minimum number of Discs: 3
Enter the maximum number of Discs: 2
The output should only solve for the minimum number of discs, 3 discs in this case**

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class hanoi {
    static int moves = 0;
    static boolean displayMoves = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(" Enter the minimum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner minD = new Scanner(System.in);
      String height = minD.nextLine();
      System.out.println();
      char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A'; // 'Needles'

      System.out.print(" Enter the maximum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner maxD = new Scanner(System.in);
      int heightmx = maxD.nextInt();
      System.out.println();


      int iHeight = 3; // Default is 3 
      if (!height.trim().isEmpty()) { // If not empty
      iHeight = Integer.parseInt(height); // Use that value

      if (iHeight > heightmx){
         hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
      }

        System.out.print("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves: ");
        Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = show.next();
        displayMoves = c.equalsIgnoreCase("v");   
      }

      for (int i = iHeight; i <= heightmx; i++) {     
           hanoi(i,source, destination, auxiliary);
         System.out.println(" Total Moves : " + moves);                    
      }
    }

    static void hanoi(int height,char source, char destination, char auxiliary) {
        if (height >= 1) {
            hanoi(height - 1, source, auxiliary, destination);
            if (displayMoves) {
                System.out.println(" Move disc from needle " + source + " to "
                        + destination);
            }
            moves++;
            hanoi(height - 1, auxiliary, destination, source);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling your `hanoi` method in a loop on the second to last line of your `main` method. The loop would iterate from `min` to `max`.

Thus, you would need

```
...
for (int i = iHeight; i < heightmx; i++) 
{
    hanoi(i, ...);
}
```

Your `for` loop variable `i` would then go from min to max (that is, if min = 3 and max = 6, the loop would call your `hanoi` method with 3, then 4, then 5, then 6).

--

**General advice**: It's important to name your variables well. In the future, when you're dealing with a thousand files, it can save you some frustration.

```
char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A';
```

would probably be

```
char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'A', destination = 'D';
```

and `height` would be `heightMin` if you are anyway naming your max height `heightMax`.

Comment: thank you so much. I will rename once my code is complete. There was just one minor case I forgot to mention, could you look at my edited question above? I also included code with a section commented out showing what I was thinking might work.

Comment: I am getting this error when I uncommented the if statement I added in my for loop: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Comment: What are the types that the error mentions after saying bad operand types?

Comment: Good. Please edit your question and add how you solved it. And mark an answer that helped.

Comment: please help it stopped working! I dont know what happened!!! But when the minimum discs is bigger than the max discs, it is only supposed to use the min number of discs. It worked but just stopped. Help!!! I'll edit my code

Comment: Not sure what you mean "stopped working". Do you mean it threw some exception? Or did the program end but did not show any output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40617/discussion-between-shobit-and-jseesfor3ver)

Comment: nevermind I re-did that part of my code. Haha, sorry about that, was freaking out because I was about to turn it in, ran it, and bam was not doing what it was supposed to. Appreciate your help